# How to recover deleted files on Linux Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, data-recovery, file-recovery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to recover a removed file under linux](https://superuser.com/questions/150027/how-to-recover-a-removed-file-under-linux)

I had a project directory inside my Eclipse workspace folder (on my Ubuntu Linux system)

By mistake I have overwrite this folder with a new wrong version dowloaded from Internet...

Can I recover the old deleted directory in some way?

Comment: Also see [How to recover a removed file under linux](http://superuser.com/q/150027),   [What is the best way to undelete some photos on Linux? Is there any way to use foremost to only recover files that only contain some text?](http://superuser.com/q/182157)

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you have `ext3` or `ext4` filesystem.
You may try to use program [extundelete](http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/). On official page you'll find documentation.

Hope that it helps you!

**P.S.** Recommend  you to use backups or better -- control version systems for your projects.

Comment: Which version control systems do you recommend?

Comment: This is offtopic, and it can be hollywar, but if you ask, I use it, and recommend Git (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_(software)).

But, of course, there are lot alternatives and you must choose it by your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.

The long answer is maybe.  It depends on the filesystem.  It depends on the amount of data.  It depends on how recognizable the files are.  And, most importantly, it depends on whether or not the actual areas of the disk that contained the information that you accidentally deleted have been overwritten.

How to do this is rather outside of the scope of a StackOverflow answer.  I would suggest bringing this to a professional if you care about retrieving your data.  Until then, do not mount the drive read write and if it's ext3 or 4 mount it through a loopback device to prevent journal writes.

Answer (score -2):

Your favourite search engine will probably point you towards some pages about this, for instance, I found https://askubuntu.com/questions/25311/best-tool-to-recover-removed-files